# Can you easily explain the process of deploying ionic (based on react) apps with a node backend?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, deployment, web-deployment

I recently started using react with a node server as a backend. I'm having problems to understand how to deploy such an app. I'm a beginner with ionic and deploying websites (or rather web based mobile apps) so I apologize if this is an easy/stupid question.

I searched a lot about this but my brain is still struggling to understand the deployment process. As I understand, any website have generally two parts, the frontend built with HTML/CSS/JS and the backend built with nodejs (in my case). If I want to run the app, I need to type `npm start` in the terminal right? so I'm only running the node server actually, where it will serve the HTML pages (static pages) depending on which url endpoint I wrote, right?

So deploying this is "easy" by copying the static files into a remote server and just run the nodeJs server to serve pages depending on the request, right. Therefore, is the start command here `npm start`, which will start the whole app.

I'm now using the [ionic framework](https://ionicframework.com/react) with react syntax and nodejs in the backend. There is a special command to run the ionic app (frontend), which is `ionic serve`. So if I run this the frontend will show up in the browser. Furthermore, I need to run the node server with `npm start` to handle requests. Therefore, to start my app, I need the `ionic serve` and `npm start` commands. How can this be deployed?

After some research, I read that I need to deploy the ionic app (frontend) and the backend separately. For example the ionic app would be a webapp and the server also a separate webapp (since I'm using MS Azure). The communication between them can be over rest API or web sockets as I understand. Is this the right approach to do this or there is a better/more clear way?

deploying two apps would mean that I need to pay for two apps on azure. Is there a way to minimize costs and have a functional app?

PS: generally, I'm having problems to understand the deployment process. I understand basically how the web works and I can build website on my machine but I'm not confident about my skills when it comes to deployment. Surprisingly, there is not much on the internet about it. Can someone please recommend articles, books or ideally videos that explain this process. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you deploy ionic apps as pwa - https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/pwa

if you are using a node backend, the you would start the server same as you would normally, If I am understanding the question

Answer (score -1):

Though your question is not specific to a particular issue but highlights a wide variety of issues, i will still try to explain it.

1. Ionic is primarily used for creating `HYBRID/WEB MOBILE APPLICATIONS`. Although you can deploy the code as a website too, but you will not be able to get any benefit out of using ionic for a website only and not using react as a standalone framework.
2. Be clear on your requirement, your question talks about website and web based mobile apps. Deploying a website and a hybrid mobile application is not one and the same thing. Websites are hosted on servers, mobile apps are deployed in app stores.
3. If you are not going to deploy to any mobile platform, i suggest you drop ionic and build your website with react.
4. Now coming to Ionic mobile apps, this is the flow

`Create Ionic Project -> Build project for iOS/Android platform -> Deploy these apps to respective app stores`

5. You will not host your Ionic mobile code on any hosting provider.
6. Your node.js backend code gets hosted on a hosting service. The endpoint URL will change to your hosted servers IP address.
7. Read about following topics first

   - What are hybrid mobile applications
   - What is Ionic
   - How to build mobile apps using Ionic
   - Publishing Mobile Applications
   - Deploying node.js to a cloud host

Comment: please read again.. the question says `web based mobile apps`.. assuming the question to be for PWA's only is also not correct... that is why i have written that the requirement is not clear..